# Fetch data from two joined tables using laravel eloquent

Tags: orm, module, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables, modules `(id,module_name)` and sub_modules`(id,module_id,sub_module_name)`.
I want to display a table like this structure:

```
Sub Module ID | Module Name | Sub Module Name
```

Modules.php (Model)

```
class Modules extends Eloquent {

 protected $table = 'modules';

 public function submodules()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('SubModules','module_id');
 }
}
```

SubModules.php (Model)

```
class SubModules extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'sub_modules';

  public function modules() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Modules');
  }

  public function nodes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Nodes','sub_module_id');
  }
}
```

AdminController.php (Controller)

```
  public function subModules() {
     return View::make('sub-modules',
                        array('title'=>'Sub-Modules',
                       'modules'=>Modules::all(),
                       'sub'=>Modules::with(array('submodules'))->get()                 
                      )
     );
  }
```

In my sub-modules view, I am fetching the `$sub` variable like this:

```
@foreach ($sub as $sub)
   <tr class="gradeX">
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $sub->id }}" id="check_{{ $sub->id }}"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ $sub->module_name }} 
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ $sub->sub_module_name }} 
      </td>
      <td>
          <a onclick="edit_sub_module({{ $sub->id }})" title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit icon-2x"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

It's not displaying contents from sub_modules table($sub->sub_module_name), only showing from modules. How to solve this? And also  there is `id` field in both tables and I need only the id from sub_modules.

Comment: Solved problem with this :

   SubModules::join('modules', 'modules.id', '=','sub_modules.module_id')->select('sub_modules.*','modules.module_name')->get() . But anyone knows how to do this with eloquent relation ?

Comment: It would be better if you could make your comment an answer so that people will see it when they find your question.

Comment: @Anshad as Phil says, put it as an answer. Eloquents relationships will not build a result set for you the way you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved problem with this :

```
SubModules::join('modules', 'modules.id', '=','sub_modules.module_id')
->select('sub_modules.*','modules.module_name')->get‌​()
```

But anyone knows how to do this with eloquent relation ?

Comment: ,do you how to do this with eloquent relation ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public function subModules() {
     return View::make('sub-modules',
                        array('title'=>'Sub-Modules',
                       'modules'=>Modules::all(),
                       'sub'=>Modules::with('submodules')->get()                 
                      )
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call in your AdminController.php

```
$module = new \App\Module::find(1); // put needed module_id;
$submodules = $module->submodules()
    ->join('modules', 'modules.id', '=','sub_modules.module_id')
    ->select('sub_modules.*','modules.module_name')
    ->get‌​();
```

`$module->submodules()` returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` class and could call `join()`, `select()`, etc. for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get sub module data without using "get()"

$submoduledata = Module::find($id)->subModule()->get();